# dual rail DC/DC convertor and CMC

Tags: dc-dc-converter, noise, inductor, common-mode, common-mode-choke

I have a DC/DC convertor that tales 5V and makes + 15V and -15V rails

My question is how to place common mode chokes to reduce common mode noise. Should I place 3 of them (1 on the negative to Gnd , 2 on positive to GND and 3 on the +15V and -15V) or 2 of them will suffice (1 on positive to Gnd and 2 on negative to GND)

Comment: I'd just use one common mode choke on the 5V input side.

Comment: why not on the output ?

Comment: Common mode currents flow on both conductors (supply and return) and so providing a higher impedance on the input should effectively block the common mode current path from the outputs back to whatever is generating the common mode voltage.  If you look at a typical multi-output offline power supply the common mode choke is always on the input side, not on each output.

Comment: Hi John , great answer I want to chose it..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Common mode currents flow on both conductors (supply and return) and so providing a higher impedance on the input only should effectively block the common mode current path from the outputs back to whatever is generating the common mode voltage. If you look at a typical multi-output offline power supply the common mode choke is always on the input side, not on each output.